# Automatically move taskbar when rotating screen

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, display-rotation

I have a Windows 8 tablet-laptop combo with which I have an issue.

To save space, I keep my task bar at the left side of the screen. This is fine when using the device in landscape mode, but when I rotate it to portrait, the task bar still occupies the left side, which is now one of the wide sides. This takes up a lot of space, so I would like the task bar to stay in the same absolute position when rotating (i.e. left side in landscape, top side in portrait). 
Is there any first- or third-party solution to this out there?

Comment: Perhaps [this script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14370485) can be made to run automatically somehow.